# How to invert this metric?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor

Reading this 
[article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.08575)
i find a result that i am not sure how to obtain (page 3 eq 3). It is about the inversion of a metric of the type
$$
g_{\mu\nu}=Al_{\mu\nu}+BH_{\mu\nu}.
$$ 
In order to invert this metric i thought to write the inverse metric as
$$
g^{\mu\nu}=al^{\mu\nu}+bH^{\mu\nu}
$$
and then imposing the relation
$$
g_{\mu\alpha}g^{\alpha\nu}=\delta_\mu^\nu
$$
i was hoping to obtain the desired result but this is not the case. I am asking for suggestions, hints or references.

Comment: Remember that you can always invert a metric by writing its components in matrix form and then inverting the matrix. With that in mind, you may be able to use this answer to find what you're looking for: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/17776/

Comment: @user35736 really thanks for the reference!!